# Add jsp file to ear

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, ear

I wanted to add a .jsp file to an ear that is deployed at a client site. What would be the process for doing this? Keep in mind I'm very new to the java world. It's going to be a simple keepalive page that doesn't have to interact with other pages. It would be ideal to not have to recreate/redeploy the entire ear because there is stress involved in getting it back to the secured client site. We'd rather give the client instructions to add the page we send them into the ear they have. They can then redeploy it.

Thanks. If I missed any information let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A JSP page is the source file that is compiled to a Java object by your application server. While deploying via an EAR or WAR is the traditional way, some servers, like Tomcat, can also deploy from an expanded EAR or WAR file. This is because EAR and WAR files actually just ZIP files, with a specific folder structure and information files in them.

You could always just try to send them the JSP page and simply have them copy and paste it into the deployment folder, overwriting the old file. Your application container *should* recognise that the source is newer than the compiled JSP page and recompile it for you on the fly when you refresh that page.

This works quite well in Tomcat - we often simply paste JSP files during development into the deployed application folder to test small changes.

Answer (score 2):

JSPs have to sit inside a WAR, which in turn sits inside the EAR.  If you already have a WAR inside the EAR, then put it in that, or add another WAR with just the JSP inside. It can't sit directly in the EAR itself.

If rapid redeployment is what you need, then an EAR really isn't the best approach...